# Search 2 columns for matches

Tags: excel, vba

I have a sheet that contains email addresses in both Column A and Column B - there are over 8000 records in Column A, and 3000 in Column B.

`C6` and `D6` are populated with either a `0` or a `1`. Not all of our O365 users have  WebEx licenses. So, Column `A` contains email addresses of O365 users, and Column `B` contains email addresses of WebEx users. Column `B` is pasted from another worksheet, and may contain duplicates depending on the O365 license that they have.

All data can be copied as values.

End goal is to search for an email address in Column A, find the match in Column B, copy the all associated rows to the Output sheet, however this code appears to just paste values in, even though they don't match. This does happen in the workbook containing this code, and the source worksheet has a name of "Sheet1"

For example:

[image]

After I run the code, this is the output. It appears to be copying all of the data in other columns, however the email addresses aren't matching:

[image]

Is there any way that I can find each of the matching values from Column A and B, take the email address and all other associated columns according to Column B's email address, and output like so (in this case, there are only 4 matches)

[image]

Code below (I do not take credit for this code, it was written by someone else):

```
Sub SearchForString()
   Const ASearchRow = 2
   Const BSearchRow = 2
   Dim CopyToRow As Integer
   Dim rng1 As Range
   Dim rng2 As Range
   Dim cell As Range
   Dim found As Range

   'Start copying data to row 2 in Sheet2 (row counter variable)
   CopyToRow = 2

   Set rng1 = Range(ActiveSheet.Cells(ASearchRow, 1), ActiveSheet.Cells(ASearchRow, 1).End(xlDown))
   Set rng2 = Range(ActiveSheet.Cells(BSearchRow, 2), ActiveSheet.Cells(BSearchRow, 2).End(xlDown))

   For Each cell In rng1

   Set found = rng2.Find(what:=cell, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole, 
   MatchCase:=False)

   If Not found Is Nothing Then

   cell.EntireRow.Copy Destination:=Sheets("Output").Range("A" & CopyToRow)

   CopyToRow = CopyToRow + 1

   End If

   Next cell

End Sub
```

Comment: Are there duplicates in any of the columns? Why do you need both columns in the resulting worksheet if they are the same?

Comment: Sorry, added code. Yes, there are a few duplicates. I took an export of email addresses from one spreadsheet, and pasted it into another spreadsheet. Column A contains users who are in our 365 tenant that have a WebEx license, Column B are just 365 accounts that have Office. Trying to determine who has both Office and WebEx licenses, and whether or not they are on Mac or PC platforms, which is indicated by a 0 or a 1 in Column C and D. It is my understanding that Range(Cells) only supports 2 values and a union was required. Didn't seem efficient. I appreciate your help.

Comment: Since you are using `EntireRow`, I'm wondering if there is more than 4 columns. Also do the email addresses contain additional data, or could they be just copied as values (do you need them as links)?

Comment: Sure, values would be fine. There are more than 4 columns, I just used the above screenshots as examples. This code actually copies all of the columns.

Comment: In the first image, shouldn't cells `C6` and `D6` be empty? From the info provided, I am assuming that there are as many records as in column `B`. Column `A` was just pasted from the other worksheet. Also the duplicates are in column `A`. Additionally the resulting records count cannot be greater (most probably will be less) than the count of cells in column `B`. Can the data in the other columns be copied as values, too? Does this happen in the workbook containing this code? Does the source worksheet have a name? Please do provide the additional info in the comments or better in your post.

Comment: Hello @VBasic2008. I added the detail into my original post. Thank you!

Comment: That's much better, but there is still one important issue I cannot understand: the association of the 'other' columns. To column `A` or to column `B`? In your second example (wrong) you are showing that the 'other' columns are associated to column `A`, while you're in the third example showing that they are associated to column `B` i.e. how many rows are there in the other columns? 3000 or 8000? For example, if the value in `A2` is found in `B5`, what should be copied, `C2:lastcol2` or `C5:lastcol5`? I would rather copy only one of those same address columns and give it a title `email`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I appreciate your attention to my post. I was able to resolve this a different way by pulling those email addresses in from a csv, and then grabbing a few device properties from the Azure registered devices. To be honest, I am no good with Excel VB, and I work with Powershell more often.

```
<#
.SYNOPSIS
Retrieves user properties via Azure AD, and supports AD User Extensions.
.DESCRIPTION
The script will import values from a csv with a header of mail. The csv file contents must be email addresses. 
The script will then query Azure AD, and retrieve various attributes for the users in the csv, and their associated devices. 
These are added to a Powershell object, and then exported to a csv. 
.EXAMPLE
.\Import-CSV-Get-Devices.ps1
#>

Connect-AzureAD

$Result = @()

$users = import-csv "C:\temp\webex-users.csv"

foreach ($user in $users) {
    $mail = $user.mail
    $results = Get-AzureADUser -ObjectId $mail | select-object userprincipalname,objectid
    $user = $_
    Get-AzureADUserRegisteredDevice -ObjectId $mail | ForEach-Object {
            $Result += New-Object PSObject -property @{ 
            DeviceOwner = $mail
            DeviceName = $_.DisplayName
            DeviceOSType = $_.DeviceOSType
            ApproximateLastLogonTimeStamp = $_.ApproximateLastLogonTimeStamp
           } 
    }
}
           
    
$Result | Select DeviceOwner,DeviceName,DeviceOSType,ApproximateLastLogonTimeStamp

$Result | Export-CSV "C:\temp\webex-user-devices.csv" -NoTypeInformation -Encoding UTF8
```